# How to generate a large data set using hive / spark-sql?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

E.g. generate 1G records with sequential numbers between 1 and 1G.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create partitioned seed table

```
create table seed (i int)
partitioned by (p int)
```

---

Populate the seed table with **1K** records with sequential numbers between 0 and 999.
Each record is being inserted into a different partition, therefore located on a different HDFS directory and more important - on a different file.

P.s.

The following set is needed

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=1000;
set hive.hadoop.supports.splittable.combineinputformat=false;
set hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat;
```

---

```
insert into table seed partition (p)
select  i,i 
from    (select 1) x lateral view posexplode (split (space (999),' ')) e as i,x
```

---

Generate a table with **1G** records.
Each of the **1K** records in the seed table is on a different file and is being read by a different container.
Each container generates **1M** records.

```
create table t1g
as
select  s.i*1000000 + e.i + 1  as n
from    seed s lateral view posexplode (split (space (1000000-1),' ')) e as i,x
```

Comment: Brilliant approach

Comment: @PraveenKumarKrishnaiyer - Thanks :-)